# Proving distance inequality between three elements in a normed linear space

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces

For any two elements $x,y$ belonging to a normed linear space, distance between x and y is given by $\rho(x,y) = ||x-y||$

I am trying to prove the inequality
$\rho(x,y) \leq \rho(x,z) + \rho(y,z)$

I've tried a bit using the norm inequality $||x+y|| \leq ||x|| + ||y||$ but I can't seem to work it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: we can write

$$\vert\vert  x-y \vert\vert=\vert\vert(x-z)+(z-y)\vert\vert$$

Alternatively (really the same method) you can try and use the triangle inequality backwards. You know the right hand side is

$$\rho(x,z)+\rho(y,z)=\vert\vert x-z\vert\vert+\vert\vert y-z\vert\vert=\vert\vert x-z\vert\vert+\vert\vert z-y\vert\vert$$
Now what can we say about our last expression?
$$\vert\vert x-z\vert\vert+\vert\vert z-y\vert\vert\ge \,\,?$$

Comment: Thanks! That was very concise.